Laravel : installation shoppingcart failed
//my composer.json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "version": "11",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.0.1"
    },

//my command prompt
C:\Users\projet\eshop>composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update gloudemans/shoppingcart
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 
  Problem 1
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart[1.0, ..., 1.2.1] require illuminate/support ~4 -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.2.17] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 1.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.0.0, ..., 2.1.2] require illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.2.45] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.4] require illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.3.23] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.5.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.5.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.6.39] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.7.28] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires gloudemans/shoppingcart * -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[1.0, ..., 1.3, 2.0.0, ..., 2.6.0].
 
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart:^2.1" if you know which you need.
 
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

For my e-shop project, i need to add a product to cart. I ran composer require g loudemans/shoppingcart and i got this Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content
I understand that this dependency is too old but how can i fix it please ? I read many topics on internet with no results. Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

gloudemans is outdated and doesn't work with Laravel 11. Check out one of the many forks and see if there's one that you like. I use anayarojo/shoppingcart, but check around for one that fits your needs.

Keep in mind that the package you want to use has not seen any activity since more than five years

Option 1: Use a Fork or Alternative Package
Some of the developers out there created forks or alternative packages that are compatible with newer versions of Laravel:
Run:
composer require bumbummen99/shoppingcart

Option 2: Use an Updated Cart Package

Darryldecode Cart: A flexible shopping cart package,

Run:
composer require darryldecode/cart


Laravel Shoppingcart: A shopping cart implementation for Laravel.

Run:
composer require devmarketer/shoppingcart

